# Set platform specific control to only one platform in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page that contains a `listview` and `Search bar` control. There is a custom `listview` for android. My code as following:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
            <ContentView>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                    <OnPlatform.iOS>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                            <SearchBar x:Name="IosSearch"
                                   Placeholder="Search"
                                   TextChanged="IosSearchBar_OnTextChanged"
                                   SearchButtonPressed="OnSearch" BackgroundColor="#19588F">
                            </SearchBar>   
                            <ListView x:Name="EmpListViewIos"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding EmpModel.GroupedItems}"
                                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
                                      SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="8">
                                                <StackLayout Spacing="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="15"  TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Spacing="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Department}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#F68933" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </OnPlatform.iOS>
                    <OnPlatform.Android>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="androidListView">  
                            <SearchBar x:Name="DroidSearch"
                                   Placeholder="Search"
                                   TextChanged="DroidSearchBar_OnTextChanged"
                                   SearchButtonPressed="OnSearch" BackgroundColor="#19588F">
                            </SearchBar>
                            <local:CustomListView x:Name="customListView"
                                  Items="{Binding EmpModel.Items}"
                                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MyListItemSelected="nativeListView_ItemSelected"
                                  SeparatorColor="Black">
                            </local:MyListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </OnPlatform.Android>
                    <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <SearchBar x:Name="WinSearch"
                               Placeholder="Search"
                               TextChanged="WinSearchBar_OnTextChanged"
                               SearchButtonPressed="OnSearch" BackgroundColor="#19588F">
                        </SearchBar>
                             <ListView x:Name="EmpListViewWin"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding EmpModel.GroupedItems}"
                                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
                                      SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="8">
                                                <StackLayout Spacing="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="15"  TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Spacing="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Department}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#F68933" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                </OnPlatform>
            </ContentView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

As the representation of data is different due to that I am required `custom listview` for android according to it's layout defined. The above code works fine. The only problem is the redundancy, the search bar control is common for all platform but when I put the search bar control above the `<ContentView>` it doesn't work throws exception. Similarly the `ListView` is common for `ios` and `windows` only there is `custom listview` for `android` but I am forced to repeat the code for windows also same as `android`.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to achieve this. How can I apply platform specific condition only for `android` and common for `windows` and `ios`.

Comment: Not sure if it will work on Control level, but if you're using some kind of MVVM framework maybe you could present the user with a different Page depending on the platform they are using?

Comment: Do you use renderer for `custom list view`?

Comment: Yes, I have used renderer for custom list view.

Comment: If you inherited your `CustomListView` from `ListView`, so just create renderer for **Android** and for **iOS** don't. Let it use standard `ListView`. I think, should work. Just don't create renderer for **iOS** and use your `CustomListView`, **Android** will use renderer and **iOS** will use base `ListView` from inheritance.

Comment: That I know but if you look at my code the data source binding property for android is items > Items="{Binding EmpModel.Items}" whereas for windows and ios > ItemsSource="{Binding EmpModel.GroupedItems}", it is due to certain purpose of representation. I pass items for android whearas grouped items for ios and win.

Comment: Ohh, I see, sorry, haven't noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could share the `iOS` and `WinPhone` views using a static resource:

```
<ContentPage>
  <ContentPage.ResourceDictionary>
    <StackLayout x:Key="iosOrWpView">
      ...
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.ResourceDictionary>
  <ContentView>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View" iOS="{StaticResource iosOrWpView}" 
                WinPhone="{StaticResource iosOrWpView}">
      <OnPlatform.Android>
        <StackLayout x:Name="androidListView">  
          ...
        </StackLayout>
      </OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
  </ContentView>
<ContentPage>
```